# Load attributes dynamically in python

Tags: python, properties

I would like to load attributes dynamically in python. Should i use property or there is a better way ? Here is an example :

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__datas = None
        self.id = 30

    def loadDatas(self):
        self.__datas = {"a": "Hello", "b": "Hi"}


Test = Test()
test.a  // Call loadData and return "Hello"
test.c  // raise error
test.id // print '30'
```

Comment: This seems completely useless to me. You store the value for name a in another dictionary so that you can add it to `__dict__` the first time a is accessed. You don't save any memory or other resources here. So why not just set a and b in `__init__`?

Comment: the above is far from SOLID methodology and far from good and optimal design

Comment: __datas are loaded from sql request. I want to load the datas only if i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can just update the Test.__dict__ for every elements of the data dictionary, This is one way to do it.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Hi'}
        self.__dict__.update(self.__data)
        self.id = 30

    def add(self, key, value):
        self.__data.update({key: value})
        self.__dict__.update(self.__data)


test = Test()
print(test.a)
# print(test.c) raises error
# print(test.id) OK
test.add('c', 'b')
# print(test.c) now ok
```

Comment: No, i want to call 'loadDatas' every time i try to acces attribute

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to override the `__getattr__` method. Your solution would be:

```py
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__datas = None
        self.id = 30

    def loadDatas(self):
        self.__datas = {"a": "Hello", "b": "Hi"}

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[attr]

        self.loadDatas()

        if attr in self.__datas:
            return self.__datas[attr]

        raise AttributeError
```